# How can I make process SQS FIFO events in order but not block others on failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS FIFO queue to process events in a lambda. The events relate to customers' information. For example, there can be a `customer.update` event to update customer's address or email etc.

When I use the FIFO queue I found an issue is that if an event is failed to process, all other events in the queue will be blocked until the retry finishes which can take a couple of minutes. How can I make the retry not block other events? I have below cases:

- If a `customer update his email` fails, I'd like to block other `updating email events on the same customer`
- if a `customer update his email` fails, I don't want to block other events for other customers.
- if a `customer update his email` fails, I don't want to block events for updating other fields of the same customer like `address`, `phone number` etc.

that's been said, how can I make the queue works for above cases. I have read `group id` concept but how I can create `group id` at runtime?

I need a solution to make a FIFO queue per customer per field.

Comment: How about storing on the customer that updating email failed, and then also fail all other types of events that depend on this succeeding?

Comment: Also, what kind of scenario do you have in mind where updating the email address can fail, and then succeed a couple of minutes later? What kind of situation made it fail in the first place, that then magically is OK a few minutes later?

Comment: It can't be updating a database but the table is throttled and it will be success some time later.

Comment: You can't do this, as it would change the order in the queue. You need some custom solution for that as others suggested.

Answer (score 4):

From [Using the Amazon SQS message group ID - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html):

> When messages that belong to a particular **message group ID** are invisible, no other consumer can process messages with the same message group ID.

The reason for this is that Amazon SQS wants to **ensure that the messages within a particular group are always processed in order**. If one message in the group is currently being processed (and hence is 'invisible'), it is possible that the Lambda function might fail to process the message. If so, the message will be returned to the queue for processing *before* any later messages in the same group.

For example, **imagine a fleet of buses** sending GPS coordinates back to a queue. An app reads the messages and plots the path of each bus on a map. It is important to process each message from a given bus in FIFO order. Therefore, the Message Group ID should be set to the same value for all messages from a given bus. While a message from Bus #1 is being processed (and is 'invisible'), the FIFO queue will not provide any more messages for that bus. However, it will provide a message for whatever bus has the next message in the queue (eg Bus #2).

If you do not need to group messages together like this, then you should **provide a unique or random number as the Message Group ID**. This will prevent a message currently being processed from blocking other messages in the queue.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The question is how I can create real time group ID? If there is a new bus join the company, how can we let the application push events to SQS with a new bus ID?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When sending a message to an Amazon SQS FIFO queue, the `MessageGroupId` is provided as a parameter. It's just a string -- you can put whatever you want in that string.